# Justify Paragraph Both Left & Right Side Without Changing Width

Tags: html, css

How do you justify text so that the following:

`The Dog Ran Up The Street And The
Cat Did As Well`

appears as such:

`The Dog Ran Up The Street 
 And The  Cat Did As  Well`

Where the text wraps and both left and right sides are aligned. Ideally I would prefer not to use the width styling to complete this. Not sure what to call this issue either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `text-align: justify;`.
To make this property work correctly you need to add `:after`.

The problem is how to align the last line of a text.
Property [text-align-last](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp) specifies how to align the last line of a text. But it has bad browser support. So we can make a hack. `:after` adds empty line after the text. So `text-align` property works correctly on your visible rows. And we shouldn't align the last line of a text (this line is made by `:after`).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    The Dog Ran Up The Street And The Cat Did As Well
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great. Can you explain what you did with the `p:after`?

Comment: @TsTeaTime added explanation.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
justify-content:space-between;
```

Comment: `justify-content` property can only be used with `display: flex`. But there is no `display: flex`.